# Creating a CLI: What should I do with the password in the config file (and how)?

Tags: encryption, go, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI with Go and I want to save the password to a config file that is saved in the user home directory.

Should I encrypt the password on save and decrypt it when sending it to the server the CLI interact with?

And if so, is there a good built in library in go library to do so? I want to keep it as simple as possible and without using any additional outside packages. All the answers I saw was quite complex.

Should be something like this:

```
func Encrypt(password string) string
func Decrypt(password string) string
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever you do, storing a password in any form and decoding it just by your app without a secret info from the user (e.g. another password) is just as insecure.

Comment: So how does any CLI (docker e.g.) saves my  password to the docker config file if I didn't put any secret?

Comment: I don't know how Docker does it, most likey using AES with a secret key saved in Docker's code or in some other file. But if someone can access Docker's code or this key file, the encrypted password can be decrypted just as easily. This only has the advantage of not seeing the cleartext password from the comfig file. Go's standard library supports the AES algorithm, you can do the same.

Comment: Yes, the main goal is just so that there is no plain test password written in a file. But I guess base64 will be just like encrypting the password without any secret. Thanks!

Comment: No. Go with AES approach. Like ask the user a  regular password (kinda easy to remember) and generate the password for the docker config file with a tool like pwgen. Then encrypt this password with the user password. Dont forget to put the right permission on the file also !!

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: The core lib does not provide this functionality out of the box. There is a third party lib for Go (from Docker) which can help.

Modern Operating Systems provide tools and APIs to store secrets in a secure way.

- Apple: Keychain
- Linux: Secret Service
- Windows: Credentials Manager API

Git and Docker uses these tools to store your credentials.

David Calavera who contributed [Docker credential helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) to Docker Engine v1.11 wrote an article titled [Stop saving credential tokens in text files](https://medium.com/@calavera/stop-saving-credential-tokens-in-text-files-65e840a237bb) in 2016. The article describes the problem, a simple implementation for Linux and shows how to use the library.

```golang
package main

import (
  "github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/client"
  "github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/credentials"
)

var nativeStore = client.NewShellProgramFunc("docker-credential-secretservice")

func main() {
  c := &credentials.Credentials{
    ServerURL: "https://api.github.com",
    Username: "token",
    Secret: "my-super-secret-token",
  }
  
  client.Store(nativeStore, c)
  storedCreds, err := client.Get(nativeStore, "https://api.github.com")
}
```

**The drawback of Docker credential helpers is that it expects you to install its binaries and needs CGo.** I added the Docker solution specifically because it was mentioned in the comments but **there are similar libraries**:

- [99designs/keyring](https://github.com/99designs/keyring) - Originally was part of AWS vault lib.
- [zalando/go-keyring](https://github.com/zalando/go-keyring) - A pure Go implementation which goal was to avoid C bindings.